# My parked domain was de-indexed by Google - what to do?

Tags: seo, google-search, google-index

I have a question about how to handle my domain.  In a nutshell, I bought a domain last year from Go Daddy.  My intention was to launch a real site with this domain and I have spent the last year working on my site.  For the last year, I have been using the default Go Daddy page display for an up and coming site.

When I first bought this site, it was indexed by Google - you could search for "alphabanter" and my site would show up on the search result page for Google.  Several months ago, it seemed Google de-indexed my domain and if you type "alphabanter," my domain no longer shows up on the list of search results.  However, if you search for "www.alphabanter.com", that's the only way it shows up in the search results for Google.

Anyways, I am about to launch my site for real.  However, I don't quite know if I can get my site back into Google's index.  I have a few questions:

1) Was my domain permanently penalized by Google and removed from their index just because it was a parked domain?  I don't believe I have done anything abusive other than using the Go Daddy default page for almost a year because my site was not ready.

2) Should I just launch my site, put a few backlinks to my site, and hope that Google indexes my site again?

3) Should I submit my site to Google at [Google submit your content](http://www.google.com/submityourcontent/website-owner/)

I assume getting Google to reconsider my site is the last option if none of the above works.

Comment: Your paranoia will disappear after you've launched your full fledged site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not permanently, no. Google apparently tries to detect parked domains and remove them from the index, which is a sensible enough policy. This process [hit the news](http://www.seroundtable.com/google-update-april-2012-15023.html) earlier this year when it accidentally produced a few false-positives.
2. Basically, yes. Follow [Google Guidelines](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35769), promote your site, and monitor in GWT.
3. It certainly won't hurt.

I doubt a reconsideration request will be necessary. Sounds like it's just the fact that it's a parked domain. As soon as Googlebot sees an actual site, and assuming it's not breaking any guidelines, I'm sure it'll be indexed.