# How do I prevent site from getting indexed when I buy the domain?

Tags: domains, search-engine-indexing

I am buying new domains, and as soon as I buy them I can find them indexed on google with "Domain Registered at Safenames" when I search `site:domainname`.

Before I buy the domain, I google the domain name and there is nothing. Is there a way I can prevent this?

Comment: You generally don't have to do anything.  Google has a [parked domain classifier algorithm](http://searchengineland.com/google-parked-domains-scraper-sites-targeted-amongsearch-changes-103302) that automatically detects parked domains and doesn't index them  It sounds like their algorithm isn't working well for Safenames.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you point your domain to your webserver and add a robots.txt with disallow directive for all. That will prevent search engines to index your domain. The best part with this solution is that search engines will ignore your content when you start buildig your new website until you remove the disallow directive. So it will not show in the serp.

Another option is to remove your dns entry so search engines and browsers/visitors can't resolve the host i.e. remove the parking.

Usually your domain name will appear in listings with newly bought domains which basically means that their listing will get any organic traffic with search querys equal to your domain name.

Answer (score 1):

Google generally avoid to index such type of site, because it has [no value for users](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66376?hl=en). But if they index it, then after few months [they will remove it automatically.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/36169/my-parked-domain-was-de-indexed-by-google-what-to-do)

But if you simply don't want to index then here is two solution you can try.

1. Redirect your domain.com to google.com by using Domain Forward option. So when Googlebot see 301 HTTP status code while crawling then Googlebot also follow that redirection and index only final(destination) URL.
2. Use reliable free host(If you don't have any host) like [github pages](https://pages.github.com/), [google cloud storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website), [blogger.com](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/41373?hl=en)  and place [noindex meta tags on `<head>` section](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en).